# Adapting this zoom effect slider to make it responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

Im looking to create a responsive zoom slider. I have used zoomslider as a base model and adjusted the code to make it responsive using a responsive grid as the base.

I am having trouble with the images now.

My problem is. If i define the image size it wont have the zoom effect once it starts to become responsive.

If you can take a look at my html and css it will help you see what I am after.

Html

```
<div id="zoom-slider">
                                        <img src="img/js-slideshow-0.jpg" />
                                        <img src="img/js-slideshow-1.jpg"/>
                                            <img src="img/js-slideshow-2.jpg"/>
                                        <img src="img/js-slideshow-3.jpg"/>
                                    </div>
```

This is my Css

```
/* http://www.menucool.com */

#zoom-slider {
    width:100%;height:400px;/* Make it smaller than your images for zooming effect */
    max-width:940px;
    border:10px solid #363f49;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;/*make the image slider center-aligned */
    border-radius:3px;
}

#zoom-slider img {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
}

/* navigation bullets wrapper */
div.navBulletsWrapper  {
    top:-40px;
    left:43%;
    background:none;
    padding-left:20px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:8;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* each bullet */
div.navBulletsWrapper div 
{
    width:12px; height:12px;
    background:transparent url(../img/bullets.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    float:left;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:11px;/* distance between each bullet*/
    _position:relative;/*IE6 hack*/
}

div.navBulletsWrapper div.active {background-position:0 -12px;}


/* --------- Others ------- */
#zoom-slider img
{
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    #zoom-slider {
        width:100%;height:250px;/* Make it smaller than your images for zooming effect */
        border:6px solid #363f49;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {



}
```

Comment: I think you should add either the `html` and/or `css` tag to your question.

Comment: If you want an existing responsive zoom slider, how about this alternative:
http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/kenburner-responsive/